# Can you use Future/Futuretask objects with Spring TaskExecutors?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency, future, futuretask

Is it possible to use Java [FutureTask](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) with a Spring TaskExecutor to get a [Future](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object?

I'm looking for a TaskExecutor that implements the Java [ExecutorService](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) interface, in particular the submit() method. Looking through the [Spring Javadocs](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/package-summary.html) doesn't reveal any classes like this. Is there some alternate method to handle futures through Spring TaskExecutors that I am unaware of?

If it is possible, could you also include an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring 3 has added submit methods with support for Future objects to [AsyncTaskExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/AsyncTaskExecutor.html). Until then if you want access to Future objects I think you will need to get the underlying JDK executor (e.g. using [getThreadPoolExecutor](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#getThreadPoolExecutor%28%29)) and submit tasks directly on that.

Comment: Not that I know of as the Spring class simply passes its calls onto the underlying executor.

Comment: Strange they didn't expose some methods until Spring 3.0.